# jquery hide() method is not working on tablet/mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, tablet, browser-detection

I have a JS function which only show one li element and hides all other li elements enclosed an unordered list based on device detection condition.

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_mostPopular"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_slots"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_table"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_roulette"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_poker"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_mobileiOS"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_mobileAndroid"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_mobileWinPhone"></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function deviceDetectionScript() {

    var mobileDetection = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

    if (mobileDetection.mobile()) {

        if (mobileDetection.os() == 'iOS') {
            alert('iOS detected'); //alert is working fine on ipad
            $('ul#menu > li').not('#mainMenuGroup_mobileiOS').hide(); // this is not working
            show_tab_content('mobileiOS'); // this function makes the selected li active - working fine
        } 
        else if (mobileDetection.os() == 'AndroidOS') {
            alert('Android detected'); //alert is working fine on android tab
            $('ul#menu > li').not('#mainMenuGroup_mobileAndroid').hide(); // this is not working
            show_tab_content('mobileAndroid'); // this function makes the selected li active - working fine
        } 
        else if (mobileDetection.os() == 'WindowsMobileOS' || mobileDetection.os() == 'WindowsPhoneOS') {
            alert('windows detected'); //alert is working fine on windows phone
            $('ul#menu > li').not('#mainMenuGroup_mobileWinPhone').hide(); // this is not working
            show_tab_content('mobileWinPhone'); // this function makes the selected li active - working fine
        }

    }
}
```

I tried using alert inside the loop and the detection is working just fine along with one additional function `show_tab_content('listID');` All these seems to be working fine apart from jquery `hide()` method `$('ul#menu > li').not('#listID').hide();`

I tried adding the else condition to check if it is not a mobile device and the script works fine on desktop browsers.

```
function deviceDetectionScript() {

    var mobileDetection = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

    if (mobileDetection.mobile()) {

        if (mobileDetection.os() == 'iOS') {
            // Same as above
        } 
        else if (mobileDetection.os() == 'AndroidOS') {
            // Same as above
        } 
        else if (mobileDetection.os() == 'WindowsMobileOS' || mobileDetection.os() == 'WindowsPhoneOS') {
            // Same as above
        }

    }
  else {
        alert('Desktop detected'); //alert is working fine on desktop
        $('ul#menu > li').not('#mainMenuGroup_poker').hide(); // this is working fine on desktop
        show_tab_content('poker'); // this function makes the selected li active - working fine
  }
}
```

Is there anything I need to make sure that the hide() method also works on mobile/tablets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced some issue while dealing with mobile devices.

Can you please try this code instead

```
$('ul#menu > li').not('#mainMenuGroup_poker').each(function(){
var unwanted_li = $(this);
unwanted_li[0].style.display = 'none';
});
```

I have not tested the above code but I think it will work.

To add, the zero index of unwanted_li have the DOM reference of the object.

******** Exact Issue and Solution ********

After long investigation, this is what was the exact reason for this not working on mobile.

Two functions were working parallely in this scenario. One was calling as soon as the JS starts executing and the other one on document.ready.

In this scenario, document.ready was called even before the other function stopped working and hence there was no li which this function can hide.

For example (function names have been changed to keep the details confidential)

At line 1245

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    abc(false,true); // this is the function which was actually adding the li s
</script>
```

At line 1456

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Device detection
    $(document).ready(function() {
        hidingScript();
    });
</script>
```

So, in above case hidingScript started executing even before abc stopped loading html. To prevent this suggested change is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Device detection
    $(document).ready(function() {
        abc();
        hidingScript();
    });
</script>
```

**In case abc is calling an ajax which is then appending the html, then you need to call hidingscript in the success event of ajax call

This change has been verified and is working fine.

Comment: That's essentially what `.hide()` does.

Comment: Right Barmar. But if he is using hide to jQuery reference instead of DOM reference, the javascript events that may have been part of other JS will not be triggered. But they will trigger if he will hide using the DOM refereence.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. There are no events associated with hiding an element or changing its style. jQuery doesn't use magic to do its work, when you call `.hide()`, it just sets the `display` style to `none`, just like your code does.

Comment: Barmar, As the below code, you can definitely add an event on hide
$('#foo').on('hide', function() {
      console.log('#foo is hidden');
});
jQuery is definitely full of magic :)

Comment: Such events are not triggered when on mobile. I am not sure of the reason of this behaviour. But this is the issue I faced earlier and got that fixed as per the solution suggested

Comment: I'm trying it in Chrome on desktop, no event is triggered.

Comment: Anyway, his question has nothing to do with events. He says the elements aren't being hidden when he calls `.hide()`. I find that difficult to believe.

Comment: Not sure but I am just guessing whether enclosing hide() inside settimeout might help me in this case?

Comment: Barmar some more piece of code is required to make hide event work. I have updated the fiddle. Please check :)

Comment: Zaq have you got a chance to check the solution I suggested. Is it working ? I dont think settimeout will work in this scenario.

Comment: I will check it now and get back to you.

Comment: @Aman Chhabra Unfortunately your solution didn't work either and result is the same as before. i.e Every li element is visible on mobile/tablet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58229/discussion-between-aman-chhabra-and-zaq).